# How ASP.NET Core validates Cookies?

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies

So I created an app which use basic cookie validation for admin login. Now I wonder how it validates cookie that is created when admin login. Where it stores isn't it supposed to be stored somewhere in database?

Comment: No, the cookie isn't stored. The cookie contains an encrypted version of the AuthenticationTicket that was created when the user signed on, along with an expiration date. It is assumed to be valid if it can be decrypted and the expiration has not passed. See [this article](https://andrewlock.net/exploring-the-cookieauthenticationmiddleware-in-asp-net-core/) for the gory details.